# i am getting "internal check system error"

Tags: python

I have defined a variable in the program but it is not working.
The user will input the number to view animals and enter "exit" to end the program. The program will run in a loop.

```
animals = [camel, lion, deer, goose, bat, rabbit]
x = input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view: ")
while True: 
    if x != ("exit"):
         print(animals[(int(x))])
    else: x == ("exit")
    print("See you later!")
exit
```

Comment: Can you post your full traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take input inside the while loop otherwise it will continue printing, and you cannot able to input next time

```
animals = ["camel", "lion", "deer", "goose", "bat", "rabbit"]
while True:
    x = input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view: ")
    if x != ("exit"):
         print(animals[(int(x))])
    else:
        x == ("exit")
        print("See you later!")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work. Your list elements should be in string format " "

```
animals = ["camel","lion","deer", "goose", "bat", "rabbit"]
x = int(input("Please enter the number of the habitat you would like to view: "))
while True: 
    if x != ("exit"):
         print(animals[x])
         break
    elif (x == ("exit")):
        print("See you later!")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
animals = ["camel", "lion", "deer", "goose", "bat", "rabbit"]
```

**In python , every string value should be written inside double or single quotes**

*In your code , your list elements were not in quotes.*

**But yes , its possible to have a list like yours. But then the python recognizes these as variables**

*From the code you have given , it is understandable that these variables are not assigned a value before*

**Thus you got the variable error**

Comment: @Ash1621 i didn't even given a code yet. I just helped you to correct the array declaration which you had an error. If your doubt was in logical part, please do mention it in the question .